# Using "send" method inside define_method in class_eval block

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have come across the following code in CodeSchool tutorial:

```
class MethodLogger

 def log_method((klass,method_name)
  klass.class_eval do
   alias_method "#{method_name}_original" method_name
   define_method method_name do
    puts "#{Time.now}: Called #{method_name}"
    send "#{method_name}_original"
   end
  end
 end

end
```

How can I tell what is the receiver for the "send" method in this code ? Here, the tutorial says that the class represented by "klass" is be the receiver of the "send" method. 
In case of code like this :

```
class Klass
end
k = Klass.new
k.send :hello,
```

It is obvious that k is the receiver of send and main is the sender . But in the first code sample , how can I deduce the receiver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reciever is the current value of `self`

So you can do:

```
class MethodLogger
 def log_method((klass,method_name)
  klass.class_eval do
   alias_method "#{method_name}_original" method_name
   define_method method_name do
    puts "#{Time.now}: Called #{method_name} on #{self.class}"
    send "#{method_name}_original"
   end
  end
 end
end
```

After a while you'll learn to keep track of `self` in your mind :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here , does self refer to an instance of klass or does it refer to the klass object itself ?

Comment: It refers to an instance of klass (it is not a class method but an instance method)

Comment: Sorry,I have another doubt, Isn't the define_method defined on a class and not an object ? But `klass.class_eval do end` creates instance methods .

Comment: Ah..So define_method is a private method defined on a class , but when  you use it , it defines an instance method in the receiver . I wish I wasn't so dumb!

Answer (score 1):

In this case send will get called on `self`, which will be an the instance of `klass`. By default, if the method's receiver is not specified, it will be `self`, and if there is no method on `self` named like that, the `Kernel` module will be the receiver. So in this case, the line in question will be equivalent to:

```
self.send "#{method_name}_original"
```